# Node/Express: How to check POST request body syntax and response error?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

The project is a Node/Express API server, generated by [swagger-node-codegen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-node-codegen). Its POST API needs a validator to check the syntax of the request body.

Here are two examples of the issue:

1. If POST using an empty request body,
2. If POST using a request body including more attributes than required,

the server will receive the request body and will still process as normal, which is sending values to query functions.

What is the appropriate way to check the syntax of a POST request body and response the error?

Comment: Would you like to understand in case of sending a login post that should contain eg email and password and in the absence of this information perform an error handling?

Comment: Not for login or absence only, looking for an appropriate way to use validation on request body syntax from server side, also to response errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use middlewares to check POST body values: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

```
router.post('/create', validateEmpty, (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({result: "OK"})
})

const validateEmpty = (req, res, next) => {
    let value = req.body.value;
    if(value.length === 0) {
        return res.status(500).send({
            error: "empty value"
        });
    }
    // if string value is longer than 0, continue with next function in route
    next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This helps me a lot to understand middleware functions.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) is a very good module for validating the request body syntax and values. Here is an example.

You can create a helper module `requestValidator.js` for validating all the routes request. considering a signup API.

```
const Joi = require('joi');

module.exports = {
  // auth
  validateSignUp: (input) => {
    const schema = Joi.object().keys({
      firstName: Joi.string().required(),
      lastName: Joi.string().required(),
      email: Joi.string().email({ minDomainAtoms: 2 }).required(),
      password: Joi.string().min(6).max(20).required(),
      confirmPassword: Joi.string().valid(Joi.ref('password')).required().options({
        language: { 
          any: { 
            allowOnly: 'must match password' 
          }
        }
      }),
      gender: Joi.string().required(),
      address: addressSchema.required(),
    });

    return Joi.validate(input, schema);
  },
}
```

And in your `authController.js`

```
const { validateSignUp } = require('../helpers/requestValidation');

module.exports = {
    signUp: async (req, res, next) => {
        const body = req.body;
        // validation
        const { error } = validateSignUp(body);
        if(error) return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: error
        });

        const user = await User.findOne({ email: email.toLowerCase() });
        if(user) {
            return respondFailure(res, 'the email address you have entered is already registered');
        }

      const newUser = new User(body);
      await newUser.save();

        return res.status(400).json({
            success: true,
            message: 'user registered successfully',
            data: newUser
        });
    },
}
```

you can add your entire app's request validation in `requestValidator.js` and use it in your controllers.

Comment: Many thanks! But my project includes many custom validations, so used the way of middleware functions in the last answer finally.

Answer (score 1):

**Above solutions works, but their exists a express library for validating either body, query or params**.

**You can follow following steps.**

1). Firstly install the library by this command.

```
npm install --save express-validator
```

2). Now where your routes are defined, import this

```
const { body, query, param } = require("express-validator");
```

3). Now in your route you can use either of above objects example..

```
router.post('/upload',
    [
        query('id')
            .not()
            .isEmpty()
            .withMessage('id field can not be empty')
            .matches(/^[0-9]+$/)
            .withMessage('id must be integer only'),
        body('fullName')
            .trim()
            .not()
            .isEmpty()
            .withMessage('fullName can not be empty')
            .matches(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)
            .withMessage('fullName must be Alpha only')
    ],
    userController.fetchProperty
);
```

their are number of methods are defined in the package as i used some of them in above example like isEmpty(), matches(), isInt() etc.

4). Now in your controller where your logic is defined, you first need to import this

```
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");
```

5). Now in your logic you just need to call this function by passing req, res object to it

```
const checkInputError = (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        res.status(422).json({
          message: 'failure',
          status: 422,
          errors: errors.array()
        });
    }
};
```

Now you will get whole validation error as response either applied in body, query or param.

Hope this will help you or somebody else!

You can refer here for more query.

https://express-validator.github.io/docs/